# How to get details of particular records from multiple tables in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables `StudentPersonalInformation` and `EducationQualification`

Here in MVC, I have create two model classes `StudentPersonalInformation.cs` and `EducationQualification.cs`, here I create the object of both classes in one wrapper class and that class Name is `StudentInfo.cs`

```
public class StudentPersonalInfo {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentFirstName { get; set; }
    public string StudentLastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public class EducationQualification {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Graduation { get; set; }
    public int Grad_Marks_obtain { get; set; }

    public string Grad_passing_year { get; set; }
    public stringPost Graduation { get; set; }

    public int PG_Marks_obtain { get; set; }
    public string PG_passing_year { get; set; }    
}

public class StudentInfo    
{
    public StudentPersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get; set; }
    public EducationQualification EducationalQualification { get; set; }
}
```

This is the DBContext class:

```
public class StudentDbContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StudentPersonalInfo> StudentPersonalInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationQualification> EducationQualifications { get; set; }
}
```

***And My Question is:***

How to display the details by id of particular students from both tables in one view.
Please tell me how to do this….

Comment: if you want yo make the view as strongly typed then create the class that contain the combination of both the class properties,bind the data with the class and display the data in views.

Comment: How do you know which `EducationQualification` belings to which student?

Comment: The most straight forward way here would be to create a stored procedure of the student detail and use Linq to get the data in the class format you require.

Comment: @Gert Arnold i dont have any relationship between two tables, i wanted to dispaly it by ID. thats meanthe studentinformation with its respective education qualification

Comment: But how do you know what to display then?? What is an `EducationQualification`? Is it related to students anyhow?

Comment: i have a list of all students record on index page and in every list i have provide the detail link after click on details of perticular student  it should be display only that student record

Comment: @Gert Arnold r u getting my point

Comment: Yes, but you're not getting mine, I'm afraid. How do you get the students details from the database? `EducationQualification` should have an FK to `Student`.

Comment: k,actually i m new in MVC, i dnt knw more about it,so,dont be afraid, tell me how to do this using fk

Answer (score 1):

You should make a ViewModel and in the controller action you should populate all the properties you want the view to have.

```
public class MyViewModelWithMultipleLists
{
       public List<StudentPersonalInfo> Students{ get; set; } 
       public List<EducationQualification> Educations{ get; set; }
       //etc
}
```

Comment: Is there any query for display the perticular student info by id

Comment: In order to query your context you should use LINQ. Google 'LINQ c#' you ll find a bunch of tutorials that will teach you how to query your data.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a relationship between Student and Qualification by adding a navigation property to EducationQualification, assuming each qualification has 1 student.

```
public virtual Student Student {get; set;}
```

If a student can have more than one qualification, your `StudentInfo` model would be more likely to look like this:

```
    public StudentPersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get; set; }
    public List<EducationQualification> EducationalQualification { get; set; }
```

So then you you can query the db, and because you have created a relationship between student and qualification, your query will look something like:

```
var model= (from s in Student
where s.Id = id
select new StudentInfo
{
    PersonalInfo = s,
    EducationalQualification = s.EducationQualification.ToList()
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

You would pass the results:

```
return View(model);
```

to a strongly typed View:

```
    @model StudentInfo

   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName)
   ...etc
```